# Why does this not have the perfect tense?

Tags: tense, past-perfect

> "You've met Malfoy before?" 
>       Harry explained about their meeting in Diagon Alley. 
>       "I've heard of his family," said Ron darkly. "They were some of the first to come back to our side after You-Know-Who disappeared.
>   Said they'd been bewitched. My dad doesn't believe it. He says
>   Malfoy's father didn't need an excuse **to go over to the Dark
>   Side**."
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I suspect to-infinitive needs to have the perfect tense, because their participation in the Dark Side precedes the time when Malfoy’s family excuse. Then why does it not use the tense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suspicion is not well founded. The [infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_infinitive) seems to me to be governed by the verb used in this case, not by the relative timings of the events described in the sentence.

We would say, for example,

> Malfoy's father is {**believed / thought**} **to have gone over** to the Dark Side.

but

> Malfoy's father didn't need an excuse **to go over** to the Dark Side.

Likewise,

> I don't need an excuse **to throw a party** {tonight / tomorrow night}.

but

> I didn't need an excuse **to throw a party** before or after being accepted by Harvard.

We can also say:

> He would have been the person **to save us** had he {been elected / not died before the election [CHOOSE ONE]}.

and

> He would have been the person **to have saved us** had he {been elected / not died before the election [CHOOSE ONE]}.

I can't explain why I've chosen **to have saved us** in this last sentence (it requires more knowledge of grammar than I have), but I believe that, like the previous sentence with **to save us**, it's grammatically and formally correct. But the main verb doesn't govern the choice of the form of the infinitive; rather, it seems to me that personal preference (a style choice) does.

Comment: "Malfoy's father didn't need an excuse to go over to the Dark Side." denotes Malfoy's father's attribut, not only the incident past?

Comment: Yes, the sentence in the novel describes Malfoy's father's character as well as tells us what he did in the past: went over to the dark side. My first example sentence tells us only what he is thought to have done.

Answer (score 1):

The to-infinitive of *go* is "to go"; it doesn't change because a to-infinitive doesn't have a tense. What eventually changes is the tense of the main verb, which in your case is *need*.

> He didn't need an excuse to go over to the Dark Side.

> He doesn't need an excuse to go over to the Dark Side.

> He won't need an excuse to go over to the Dark Side.

Comment: You are wrong, to have gone to X is equally correct in some contexts. See BillFrankie's anwer.

Comment: It is not in this context.